# How can I disable logging in Ruby on Rails on a per-action basis?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, conditional-statements, action

I have a Rails application that has an action invoked frequently enough to be inconvenient when I am developing, as it results in a lot of extra log output I don't care about.  How can I get rails not to log anything (controller, action, parameters, completion time, etc.) for just this one action?  I'd like to conditionalize it on RAILS_ENV as well, so logs in production are complete.

Thanks!

Comment: Wonder if you could use rack middleware somehow - so you could throw the "Rails.logger.silence" block around the complete request-response when the request matches your pattern.

Comment: I looked briefly at this.  I might have missed something, but it looked like at the time rack middleware is involved, it doesn't know what controller/action is being called.

Comment: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html  ActiveSupport::Benchmarkable#silence has been deprecated due to its lack of thread safety. It will be removed without replacement in Rails 4.1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer turns out to be a lot harder than I expected, since rails really does provide no hook to do this.  Instead, you need to wrap some of the guts of ActionController::Base.  In the common base class for my controllers, I do

```
def silent?(action)
  false
end

# this knows more than I'd like about the internals of process, but
# the other options require knowing even more.  It would have been
# nice to be able to use logger.silence, but there isn't a good
# method to hook that around, due to the way benchmarking logs.

def log_processing_with_silence_logs
  if logger && silent?(action_name) then
    @old_logger_level, logger.level = logger.level, Logger::ERROR
  end

  log_processing_without_silence_logs
end

def process_with_silence_logs(request, response, method = :perform_action, *arguments)
  ret = process_without_silence_logs(request, response, method, *arguments)
  if logger && silent?(action_name) then
    logger.level = @old_logger_level
  end
  ret
end

alias_method_chain :log_processing, :silence_logs
alias_method_chain :process, :silence_logs
```

then, in the controller with the method I want to suppress logging on:

```
def silent?(action)
  RAILS_ENV == "development" && ['my_noisy_action'].include?(action)
end
```

Comment: `alias_method_chain` is no longer used in Ruby 2.0.

Answer (score 29):

You can silence the Rails logger object:

```
def action
  Rails.logger.silence do
    # Things within this block will not be logged...
  end
end
```

Comment: That's a generally useful pattern, but ActionController::Base logs stuff before and after the action method executes, so that doesn't solve my particular problem.

Comment: This throws a deprecation warning in Rails 3. You can use `silence do ... end` instead

Answer (score 20):

Use [`lograge`](https://github.com/roidrage/lograge) gem.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'lograge'
```

config/application.rb:

```
config.lograge.enabled = true
config.lograge.ignore_actions = ['StatusController#nginx', ...]
```

Answer (score 15):

The following works with at least Rails 3.1.0:

Make a custom logger that can be silenced:

```
# selective_logger.rb
class SelectiveLogger < Rails::Rack::Logger

  def initialize  app, opts = {}
    @app = app
    @opts = opts
    @opts[:silenced] ||= []
  end

  def call  env
    if @opts[:silenced].include?(env['PATH_INFO']) || @opts[:silenced].any? {|silencer| silencer.is_a?( Regexp) && silencer.match( env['PATH_INFO']) }
      Rails.logger.silence do
        @app.call env
      end
    else
      super env
    end                        
  end

end
```

Tell Rails to use it:

```
# application.rb
config.middleware.swap Rails::Rack::Logger, SelectiveLogger, :silenced => ["/remote/every_minute", %r"^/assets/"]
```

The example above shows silencing asset serving requests, which in the development environment means less ( and sometimes no) scrolling back is required to see the actual request.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to conflict with the quiet_assets gem (https://github.com/evrone/quiet_assets).  With both enabled I get errors like ```NoMethodError: undefined method `collect' for nil:NilClass```, coming from logger.rb ```compute_tags```.

Answer (score 7):

You can add the gem to the Gemfile [silencer](https://github.com/stve/silencer).

```
gem 'silencer', '>= 1.0.1'
```

And in your config/initializers/silencer.rb :

```
  require 'silencer/logger'

  Rails.application.configure do
    config.middleware.swap Rails::Rack::Logger, Silencer::Logger, silence: ['/api/notifications']
  end
```

Comment: For some reason, I could not make this work in Rails 5.0.0.1. I get: No such middleware to insert before: Rails::Rack::Logger (RuntimeError)

Comment: Updated to support Rails 5.x @pguardiario. Now it should work ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The following works with Rails 2.3.14:

Make a custom logger that can be silenced:

```
#selective_logger.rb  
require "active_support"

class SelectiveLogger < ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger

  attr_accessor :silent

  def initialize path_to_log_file
    super path_to_log_file
  end

  def add severity, message = nil, progname = nil, &block
    super unless @silent
  end
end
```

Tell Rails to use it:

```
#environment.rb
  config.logger = SelectiveLogger.new  config.log_path
```

Intercept the log output at the beginning of each action and (re)configure the logger depending on whether the action should be silent or not:

```
#application_controller.rb
  # This method is invoked in order to log the lines that begin "Processing..."
  # for each new request.
  def log_processing
    logger.silent = %w"ping time_zone_table".include? params[:action]
    super
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

With Rails 5 it gets more complicated request processing is logged in several classes. Firstly we need to override `call_app` in `Logger` class, let's call this file `lib/logger.rb`:

```
# original class:
# https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb
require 'rails/rack/logger'
module Rails
  module Rack
    class Logger < ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber

      def call_app(request, env) # :doc:
        unless Rails.configuration.logger_exclude.call(request.filtered_path)
          instrumenter = ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrumenter
          instrumenter.start "request.action_dispatch", request: request
          logger.info { started_request_message(request) }
        end
        status, headers, body = @app.call(env)
        body = ::Rack::BodyProxy.new(body) { finish(request) }
        [status, headers, body]
      rescue Exception
        finish(request)
        raise
      ensure
        ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber.flush_all!
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Then follow with `lib/silent_log_subscriber.rb`:

```
require 'active_support/log_subscriber'
require 'action_view/log_subscriber'
require 'action_controller/log_subscriber'
# original class:
# https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/log_subscriber.rb
class SilentLogSubscriber < ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber

  def start_processing(event)
    return unless logger.info?

    payload = event.payload
    return if Rails.configuration.logger_exclude.call(payload[:path])

    params  = payload[:params].except(*ActionController::LogSubscriber::INTERNAL_PARAMS)
    format  = payload[:format]
    format  = format.to_s.upcase if format.is_a?(Symbol)
    info "Processing by #{payload[:controller]}##{payload[:action]} as #{format}"
    info "  Parameters: #{params.inspect}" unless params.empty?
  end

  def process_action(event)
    return if Rails.configuration.logger_exclude.call(event.payload[:path])

    info do
      payload = event.payload
      additions = ActionController::Base.log_process_action(payload)
      status = payload[:status]

      if status.nil? && payload[:exception].present?
        exception_class_name = payload[:exception].first
        status = ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper.status_code_for_exception(exception_class_name)
      end

      additions << "Allocations: #{event.allocations}" if event.respond_to? :allocations

      message = +"Completed #{status} #{Rack::Utils::HTTP_STATUS_CODES[status]} in #{event.duration.round}ms"
      message << " (#{additions.join(" | ")})" unless additions.empty?
      message << "\n\n" if defined?(Rails.env) && Rails.env.development?

      message
    end
  end

  def self.setup
    # unsubscribe default processors
    ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber.log_subscribers.each do |subscriber|
      case subscriber
      when ActionView::LogSubscriber
        self.unsubscribe(:action_view, subscriber)
      when ActionController::LogSubscriber
        self.unsubscribe(:action_controller, subscriber)
      end
    end
  end

  def self.unsubscribe(component, subscriber)
    events = subscriber.public_methods(false).reject { |method| method.to_s == 'call' }
    events.each do |event|
      ActiveSupport::Notifications.notifier.listeners_for("#{event}.#{component}").each do |listener|
        if listener.instance_variable_get('@delegate') == subscriber
          ActiveSupport::Notifications.unsubscribe listener
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
# subscribe this class
SilentLogSubscriber.attach_to :action_controller
SilentLogSubscriber.setup
```

Make sure to load modified modules e.g. in `config/application.rb` after loading `rails`:

```
require_relative '../lib/logger'
require_relative '../lib/silent_log_subscriber'
```

Finally configure excluded paths:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.logger_exclude = ->(path) { path == "/health" }
end
```

As we're modifying core code of Rails it's always good idea to check original classes in Rails version you're using.

If this looks like too many modifications, you can simply use [`lograge`](https://github.com/roidrage/lograge) gem which does pretty much the same with few other modifications. Although the `Rack::Loggger` [code has changed since Rails 3](https://github.com/roidrage/lograge/blob/master/lib/lograge/rails_ext/rack/logger.rb), so you might be loosing some functionality.

Comment: This options works great, though something is off with importing correct libs when running tests. it constsantly can't find some action_dispatch modules (have tried several different requires for action_dispatch)

Comment: Never mind my comment, found the problem. The problem is that by calling the modified logger class file `logger.rb` and then requiring it in application, it causes some conflicts. I renamed it to `silence_logger.rb` and all problems were resolved

Answer (score 1):

@neil-stockbridge 's answer not worked for Rails 6.0, I edit some to make it work

```
# selective_logger.rb
class SelectiveLogger

  def initialize  app, opts = {}
    @app = app
    @opts = opts
    @opts[:silenced] ||= []
  end

  def call  env
    if @opts[:silenced].include?(env['PATH_INFO']) || @opts[:silenced].any? {|silencer| silencer.is_a?( Regexp) && silencer.match( env['PATH_INFO']) }
      Rails.logger.silence do
        @app.call env
      end
    else
        @app.call env
    end                        
  end

end
```

Test rails app to use it:

```
# application.rb
config.middleware.swap Rails::Rack::Logger, SelectiveLogger, :silenced => ["/remote/every_minute", %r"^/assets/"]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Sprockets-rails](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails) gem starting from version `3.1.0` introduces implementation of [quiet assets](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/blob/v3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb). Unfortunately it's not flexible at this moment, but can be extended easy enough.

Create `config/initializers/custom_quiet_assets.rb` file:

```
class CustomQuietAssets < ::Sprockets::Rails::QuietAssets
  def initialize(app)
    super
    @assets_regex = %r(\A/{0,2}#{quiet_paths})
  end

  def quiet_paths
    [
      ::Rails.application.config.assets.prefix, # remove if you don't need to quiet assets
      '/ping',
    ].join('|')
  end
end
```

Add it to middleware in `config/application.rb`:

```
# NOTE: that config.assets.quiet must be set to false (its default value).
initializer :quiet_assets do |app|
  app.middleware.insert_before ::Rails::Rack::Logger, CustomQuietAssets
end
```

Tested with Rails 4.2

Answer (score 0):

Rails 6. I had to put this in `config/application.rb`, inside my app's class definition:

```rb
require 'silencer/logger'

initializer 'my_app_name.silence_health_check_request_logging' do |app|
  app.config.middleware.swap(
    Rails::Rack::Logger,
    Silencer::Logger,
    app.config.log_tags,
    silence: %w[/my_health_check_path /my_other_health_check_path],
  )
end
```

That leaves the `log_tags` config intact and modifies the middleware before it gets frozen. I would like to put it in `config/initializers/` somewhere tucked away but haven't figured out how to do that yet.