# How can I keep an url request from being saved in the log in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I disable logging in Ruby on Rails on a per-action basis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196828/how-can-i-disable-logging-in-ruby-on-rails-on-a-per-action-basis)

I use an ajax "ping" for keeping track of the online users, and for alerting them about notifications if any. However, this constant request are being logged in my production.log file, and that's not funny, since I want to keep track of the app performance and that just obfuscate my log file.

What should I to do?

Comment: Duplicate of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196828/how-can-i-disable-logging-in-ruby-on-rails-on-a-per-action-basis)

Answer (score 0):

You can set

```
config.log_level = :warn
```

That way only issues will be logged.

Comment: But I DO wanna log the requests. I just don't wanna log THAT request :(

Comment: Sorry then, only thing i can recomend is parsing your log files. This is why I love logging to MySQL, you just query for what you want!