# How to filter logs in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

In my Rails app production mode,I set the error log level to `error`.

But I want to set some controllers an actions(or routes) to the level `access`,so how can I realize this? If the log has a filter?

Comment: I am not sure i understand the question

Comment: That is,I want some controller and action to log `info` and the others visit log `error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [around filter](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#after-filters-and-around-filters) to adjust the logging level for an action, For example:

```
class MyBigFancyController < ApplicationController
  around_action :adjust_logging_level_to_access, only: :show

  def show
  end

  private

  def adjust_logging_level_to_access
    old_level = Rails.logger.level 
    Rails.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
    yield
    Rails.logger.level = old_level
  end
end
```

If you have to do this in many controllers, consider moving it to the ApplicationController.

Please note that [adjusting the Rails logging level at run time is not thread safe](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20490). If you require thread safety, you will need to manually write to the log in the relevant locations.

Comment: The linked http://stackoverflow.com/q/2196828/525478 has some interesting approaches, but you would have to flip them around...

Comment: Thanks,this is a good solution.But I have a question,If two user visit the page  A that has `adjust_logging_level_to_access` and the another page B without `adjust_logging_level_to_access` at the same time.So will  page B logged DEBUG?Because the log level is globle, so change the level in page A will affect the log level in page B,isn't that?

Comment: @HXH Yes, if your server is multithreaded and running multiple threads. This is a current limitation of Rails, as discussed in github.com/rails/rails/issues/20490