How to suppress an arbitrary log message in Rails?
I am using a gem that logs messages that are not useful.
How can I suppress any arbitrary log message, say with a regex? Or from for a given route or controller?
Yes, I know it is slow and not for production.

Can you provide more information? What gem are you using? What kind of messages are you trying to supress? (give us an example), what did you mean from a given route or controller? (because there is a way to silence logs in a certain block using this  (https://apidock.com/rails/Logger/silence) function)

Sidekiq. Started GET "/sidekiq/busy" for ::1 at 2024-10-03 16:07:32 -0700. The silence method takes a block, which won't work because I don't want to modify the gem. I meant for a given route or controller.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196828/how-can-i-disable-logging-in-ruby-on-rails-on-a-per-action-basis

@Alex - I saw that but did not like any of the answers.

Having said that, I liked this answer best: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66795203/336920
